# How to refer to a column in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

In Report Builder when writing expressions it is pretty straightforward to refer to fields from the DataSet (`Fields!FIELDNAME.Value`). But how does one refer to a value of another column (of the same row)? Is there something like `Columns!COLUMNNAME.Value`?

Comment: Is column's value some expression. or is it a value from dataset?

Comment: @MarkoRadivojević It's large and complicated expression, that can change in the future, that's why i don't want to simply copy/paste it

Comment: are you looking for reportitems!textboxwhatever.value ?where texboxwhatever is the name of the cell you want to refer / access ?

Comment: Yes, as @Harry said, use `ReportItems!TextBoxName.Value`.

Comment: @Harry Yes, that's what i was looking for, thanks, if you put that as answer I'll checkmark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is called ReportItems

example use :

```
 reportitems!textboxwhatever.value
```

where texboxwhatever is the name of the cell you want to refer / access